# c++ global variables

Tags: c++, windows, linker, global-variables

i have a header file `global.h` where i declare a few variables that i intend to use in other files.

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_
#define GLOBAL_H_

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct tag_KG_Data
{
   int nKGStationID;
   int nKGComPort;

 }GLOBAL_VAR;

 GLOBAL_VAR g_GlobalVar;

 BOOL b_newDataReady;
 BOOL b_startedSocketClient;



#endif
```

At first i declared  only `GLOBAL_VAR g_GlobalVar` in file `test1.cpp` with `extern GLOBAL_VAR g_GlobalVar;`, and worked just fine. Then i declared the 2 `BOOL`s and used them  in `test2.cpp`, but i get an `error LNK2005: "struct tag_KG_Data g_GlobalVar" (?g_GlobalVar@@3Utag_KG_Data@@A) already defined in test1.obj` and for every global variable i have i get a similar error. The thing is that i don't use `GLOBAL_VAR g_GlobalVar` in `test2.cpp` or any of the `BOOL`s in `test1.cpp`.

Comment: So you had something that worked, and now you've changed it and it no longer works. There's a **big** clue there.

Comment: @PeteBecker i agree, but i want to understand why is not working, not just to workaround the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you are *defining* the globals in the header, while you should be only *declaring* them.

Add `extern` in front of your global definitions, and create a definition in a single cpp file.

In the header:

```
// Declarations
extern GLOBAL_VAR g_GlobalVar;
extern BOOL b_newDataReady;
extern BOOL b_startedSocketClient;
```

In a cpp file:

```
// Definitions
GLOBAL_VAR g_GlobalVar;
BOOL b_newDataReady;
BOOL b_startedSocketClient;
```

Comment: Good answer.  One additional thing is it does not matter whether the variables are used in the .cpp file or not.  Because the .h include file defines them each time the .h file is included, a new definition of the variables is created.  So you can also get this same effect when a .h file with global variables are included by other .h files when you do hot have a #def #ifdef guard to prevent multiple inclusions.  #include is a preprocessor directive to pull the text of a file into another file and works at the textual level not the compiled code level. Almost never declare variables in .h file.

Comment: This resolved generated errors. Thanks, the answer also cleared a blurry c++ area for me :)